# Send GCM message from PHP after page load (without ajax)

Tags: php, codeigniter, asynchronous, google-cloud-messaging

Hy guys!
*My story:*
I'm making an PHP application with Codeigniter. When my page is loaded I can click a button that calls my PHP API that makes some changes in the database and returns the result (true or false if the change in the database wasn't successful). Also after the database change I call a PHP script that sends push notifications to registered android devices that are stored in my database.
*My problem*:
When there are a lot of registered android devices it takes some time to load the page (PHP is waiting for every GCM request to come back). Is there a way that I can load the page after the database changes **AND** make GCM requests in the background/async?
*EDIT #1:*
I am on a Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to address this, but the most common solution is to use some form of a message queue to offload the work to seperate processes.

You could just store the messages to a seperate table in your database and have a cron script run every few minutes to send those messages (and only delete them from the table when successfully sent) or you could look into using rabbitmq, gearman or beanstalk which are designed to be more robust and more easily scaled.

**Recommended reading:**

- http://www.slideshare.net/appdynamics/scaling-php-in-the-real-world-23619565
- https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries
- http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gearman-multi-tasking-php/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although @Samutz 's answer is good to but I like robustness more than simplicity :) ... Anyway thanks to BOTH of ya! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can separate the push code in to it's own standalone script, you could call it with

```
 exec("php /path/to/script.php > /dev/null &");
```

This should run it in the background (on Linux) without the script that calls it waiting.

Another option might be to store notifications in the database as a queue and have a script run via cron every *N* minutes to check the queue and push notifications from it.